# Leverage browser caching

Tags: html, iis, configuration, windows-server-2003, http-caching

I have a website and when I check page speed with Google plug-in, I receive:

> Leverage browser caching
>   The following resources are missing a cache expiration

Searching only returns information on using htaccess under Apache, but my site is running on Windows 2003 Server, in plain HTML language, and I don't even have access to the server.

Is there any way to specify expiration and gzip compression, as it recommends?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at Content Expiration, that should do the trick for you on the caching.

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0fc16fe7-be45-4033-a5aa-d7fda3c993ff.mspx?mfr=true

To set the expiration of Web site content

1. In IIS Manager, double-click the local computer; right-click the Web Sites folder, an individual Web site folder, a virtual directory, or a file; and then click Properties.
2. Click the HTTP Headers tab.
3. Select the Enable content expiration check box.
4. Click Expire immediately, Expire after, or Expire on, and type the appropriate expiration information in the corresponding boxes.
5. Click OK.

Comment: sir, please read my question i don't have access to the server, so how can get IIS manager and all these....

Comment: Do you have ability then to upload files?

Comment: You can always use the <META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="" /> with a date in the future. but it's not very effective, and if you are using static html you would have to hardcode your expiration date to far in future. ie <meta http-equiv="expires" content="mon, 27 sep 2012 14:30:00 GMT">

Comment: Dear Marcel Dumont, yes i have ability to upload files.

Comment: Without access the server i don't see any other option that adding the <META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="" /> tag to each document you want to cache. For GZIP compression you'll need access to the server.

Answer (score -2):

You can also Gzip by adding the code below to the top of your PHP pages.

It works great.

Comment: this is a WINDOWS server, not LAMP nor does he run PHP on it. The results he found were for Apache/htaccess WHICH HE DOES NOT RUN